# Как в Python узнать имя функции в которой выполняется код?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как в Python узнать имя функции в которой выполняется код? Желательно не устанавливая дополнительные модули.

Например 1:

```
class Test:
    def func_1():
        print(f'Print from {name_this_function}')

    def func_2():
        print(f'Print from {name_this_function}')

    def func_3():
        print(f'Print from {name_this_function}')

test = Test()
test.func_1()
test.func_2()
test.func_3()
```

Пример 2:

```
class Test:
    def func_1():
        self.where_are_you()

    def func_2():
        self.where_are_you()

    def func_3():
        self.where_are_you()

    def where_are_you():
        if current_func == 'func_1':
            print('Print from func_1')
        elif current_func == 'func_2':
            print('Print from func_2')
        elif current_func == 'func_2':
            print('Print from func_2')

test = Test()
test.func_1()
test.func_2()
test.func_3()
```

При выполнении кода хочу видеть такой вывод:

> Print from func_1
>   Print from func_2
>   Print from func_3

Comment: Какую проблему вы хотите таким образом решить?

Comment: Хочу использовать одну и ту же функцию, которая будет выполнять немного разные задачи, в зависимости от того в какой функции она вызвана. Т.е. эта функция каким то образом должна понимать, внутри какой функции она находится (вызывается).

Comment: Может этот код прояснит ситуацию? =) ```class Test:
    def func_1():
        self.where_are_you()

    def func_2():
        self.where_are_you()

    def func_3():
        self.where_are_you()

    def where_are_you():
        if current_func == 'func_1':
            print('Print from func_1')
        elif current_func == 'func_2':
            print('Print from func_2')
        elif current_func == 'func_2':
            print('Print from func_2')

test = Test()
test.func_1()
test.func_2()
test.func_3()```

Comment: Создайте параметр функции который будет указывать на то какой алгоритм нужно использовать и задавайте этому параметру значение там где вызываете функцию. Ну в вашем случае параметр функции инициализации класса

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import traceback


def say_my_name():
    stack = traceback.extract_stack()
    print('Print from {}'.format(stack[-2][2]))


class Test:

    def func_1(self):
        say_my_name()

    def func_2(self):
        say_my_name()

    def func_3(self):
        say_my_name()


test = Test()
test.func_1()
test.func_2()
test.func_3()
```

Но вообще согласен с Wairua - лучше явно передавать параметр с указанием нужной стратегии.

Comment: Спасибо, stack = traceback.extract_stack() - это то что нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```
import sys

class Test:
    def func(self):
        print(f'Print from {sys._getframe().f_code.co_name}')

test = Test()
print(test.func())
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы задаете функцию в качестве аргумента, внутри другой функции или где либо еще вызываете, имя функции можно узнать так:

`func.__name__`

В вашем примере будет:

> `print(f'Print from {func_1.__name__}')`

Comment: Это никак не применимо к данному вопросу.